# Pythonic way of handling two statements in a for loop?

Tags: python

Is this the most pythonic way of doing this -

```
ys = []
for x in xs:
    z = compute_something(x)
    #z is an object of some class
    ys.append(z.a_property_of_z)

return ys
```

or can I handle the above in some clever list comprehension? or functional programming? or some other python magic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
return [compute_something(x).a_property_of_z for x in xs]
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to do is collect the `a_property_of_z` attributes, you can combine the calculation and the attribute access:

```
return [compute_something(x).a_property_of_z for x in xs]
```

The return value of `compute_something()` can be referenced directly in the list comprehension.